# Proof of $\operatorname{Var}(\bar{x}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, variance

I'm trying to understand why we divide by $n - 1$ when calculating the variance of a sample in statistics.

Following [Wikipedia's third alternate proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction#Proof_of_correctness_.E2.80.93_Alternate_3), I get stuck on

$$\operatorname{Var}(\bar{x}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$

How would one prove of this equation?

Comment: The cop-out answer I give is "degrees of freedom."

Comment: $\operatorname{Var}(\bar{x})=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}(x_i)$ due to independence

Comment: @Sayan I'm not familiar with that formula either

Comment: @CrackerKraken May be you can look up here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_.28Bienaym.C3.A9_formula.29

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then are uncorrelated and thus $\mathsf{Var}(X+Y) = \mathsf{Var}(X) + \mathsf{Var}(Y)$. Of course this readily extends to many-variables case: for independent (or even pairwise uncorrelated) variables $X_1, \cdots, X_n$, you end up with $$\mathsf{Var}(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \mathsf{Var}(X_1) + \cdots + \mathsf{Var}(X_n).$$ This is one of the most basic properties of the variance. Together with another basic property $\mathsf{Var}(aX) = a^2\mathsf{Var}(X)$, you immediately get what Sayan mentioned.

Comment: @MarkViola : You're quite wrong on several points. Firstly you have $k$ in $\sum_{k=1}^n$ but $i$ rather than $k$ in the following expression. Secondly the expected value of $\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\mu)^2$ is indeed $\sigma^2$ (where $\mu$ is of course the population mean rather than the sample mean). There is no bias in $\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k -\mu)^2$ as an estimator of $\sigma^2;$ rather the bias is in $\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k - \overline X)^2,$ where $\overline X$ is the sample mean rather than the population mean.

Comment: Thus: $$ \begin{align} \operatorname{E}\left( (X_1-\mu)^2\right) & = \sigma^2, \\  \\ \operatorname{E}\left( \frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k - \mu)^2 \right) & = \sigma^2 \\  \\ \operatorname{E} \left( \frac 1 {n-1} \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k - \overline X)^2 \right) & = \sigma^2 \end{align} $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Obviously, the index mismatch is a typographical error.  And $\mu$ is meant as the estimate of $x$, not the actual mean.  So, when you stated that "You're wrong on several points," you were actually wrong.  First several means "more than two [See Here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/several)," yet you only listed two items.  Second, the index mismatch is a typographical error, which should be obvious.  Third, $\mu$ is meant in what I wrote as the sample mean and not the population mean.  So, Michael, please take a different tact before you leave unfounded comments. ;-))

Comment: @MarkViola : Why would you use the letter $\mu$ to refer to the sample mean rather than the population mean? That can only confuse matters. It conflicts with standard usage, and there are reasons other than arbitrary convention why the standard usage makes sense, i.e. lower-case Greek letters typically refer to unobservable parameters.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I didn't realize that one is restricted with respect to designation.  But, I understand your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}\left( \frac {X_1+\cdots+X_n} n \right) & = \frac 1 {n^2} \operatorname{var} (X_1+\cdots+X_n) \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {n^2} \big( \operatorname{var}(X_1)+\cdots+\operatorname{var}(X_n) \big) \quad \text{because of independence} \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {n^2}(\sigma^2 + \cdots+\sigma^2) \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {n^2}\cdot n\sigma^2 \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\sigma^2} n.
\end{align}